# How to remove specific lines from a file in python

Tags: python

Hey I know this has been asked a few times, but I wrote my own code for it but it isn't working and I don't see why. Here is my code

```
def fixfiles ():
    inputfilehandle = open("C:/allCHP1seq.txt","r")
    outputf=open("chp1seqs.txt","w")
    lines = inputfilehandle.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "c:\users" not in line:
            outputf.write(line)
```

Here is an example of data from the file, basically theres 279 of these in the file, separated by 2 lines. But each is unique, what I need to do is get rid of the bit at the start specifying the directory.

```
c:\users\gary\desktop\sequences for chp1\14-3 1076.txt
>fig|6666666.13395.peg.1076
atgatcaaagaaaccgaaaaaccgccaaccaccctctttaccgtcgtccc
cgacacccctaccgaaaccctgctgatcaacagctacgaaaccgtgtgtt
ccgtcagcaccctgctgctcgacttgtccgaagacctcaccggcaaacac
cgcgatatcgccttggccattcatcagttgagcgaactgagcgtcctgct
ggtgggcaaagccatggaccagcacacaccccgctgctga
```

I really don't see where I'm going wrong :/ Help!

Comment: Works fine here. Please specify what's not working about it.

Comment: What actually gets put into this file?  (I can't find an issue with your code either other than you're not closing your files when you're done).

Comment: How does it fail?  Does that forward slash in the filename need to be a(n escaped) backslash? (i.e. "C:\\allCHP1seq.txt"")

Comment: Also, note that you don't need `readlines()`.  `for line in inputfilehandle:` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should escape your `\` : `"c:\\users"` instead of `"c:\users"`.

Answer (score 3):

You should really write:

```
if r"c:\users" not in line:
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to [escape your backslash](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html). For fun, here's a one-liner solution:
`open("chp1seqs.txt","w").writelines(filter(lambda line: "c:\\users" in line, open("C:/allCHP1seq.txt","r").readlines()))`

Answer (score 0):

Just slice them out. It's more efficient than testing each line, especially when you know the issue is only with the top two lines:

```
def fixfiles ():
    inputfilehandle = open("C:/allCHP1seq.txt","r")
    outputf=open("chp1seqs.txt","w")
    lines = inputfilehandle.readlines()[2:]
    for line in lines:
        outputf.write(line)
```